# Several Columns of Figures

Tags: two-column

In the attachment of my dissertation, I would like to add some pictures. They are all .jpg files.

For my work it would make sense to place two figures next to each other with a little space between them, using up the whole width of the page except for the boarders.

Can anyone tell me how to do this? I know, it's a lot I'm asking for but I've been messing with several methodes and none of them give me the result I want.

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Jurg

Comment: does each image need a separate numbered caption?

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122313/11604) solves your problem?

Comment: Could you please add some details? Do you want captions to the images? Are the images' dimensions the same or different? How many of them do you have?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Yes, they do.

Comment: @egreg: The dimensions of the pictures are the same. I need to include 24 Pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following macro for the same purpose.

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xargs}

\newlength{\tmplength}
\newcommandx{\illustrations}[8][1=0.5, 2=htb]{%
    \setlength{\tmplength}{\textwidth}
    \addtolength{\tmplength}{-#1\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}[#2]
        \tabcolsep = 0pt
        \begin{tabular}{p{#1\textwidth}p{\tmplength}}
            \centering \includegraphics{pictures/#4} & \centering \includegraphics{pictures/#7} \tabularnewline
            \centering \captionof{figure}{\label{#3}#5} & \centering \captionof{figure}{\label{#6}#8}
        \end{tabular}%
    \end{figure}%
}
```

Usage is the following:

```
\illustrations
    [<part of page for the first picture>]
    [<position of figure>]
    {<label of the first picture>}
    {<filename of the first picture>}
    {<caption text for the first picture>}
    {<label of the second picture>}
    {<filename of the second picture>}
    {<caption text for the second picture>}
```

However all my pictures were in the “pictures” subdirectory. If you have another path you may fix it in macro. Also you can add argument(s) for scaling pictures.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. As I am very new to LaTeX, this seems quite difficult. I don't semm to get it to work. Shouldn't there be an easier way? If not, I will have to give it another try.

Comment: One more note. If you compile your `TeX`-file to `dvi` and use `graphicx` package, then `EPS` is the only supported format. If you compile it directly to `pdf` using `pdfLaTeX`, then supported formats are `jpg`, `png` and `pdf`. Use `\includegraphics` and all dependent macro (like mine) carefully. If you have any other problem, provide information about it from log-file.