# Sequence of multiple images of varying sizes

Tags: graphics, pdftex, formatting, text

Related to:

[Getting two pictures to appear on the same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134162/getting-two-pictures-to-appear-on-the-same-page)

[Placing a table next to figure (align table vertically centre)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133732/placing-a-table-next-to-figure-align-table-vertically-centre/133797#133797)

[Putting multiple images in a page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/107363/putting-multiple-images-in-a-page)

I have a sequence of images that I want stored in succession, one after the other with **no** text in between.

What I tried:

**option #1:**

```
\begin{figure}
    \centerline{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{1.png}}
    \caption{1}
    \label{fig:1}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}
    \centerline{\includegraphics[width=10cm,scale=0.5]{2.png}}
    \caption{2}
    \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centerline{\includegraphics[width=10cm,scale=0.5]{3.png}}
    \caption{3}
    \label{fig:3}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \centerline{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{4.png}}
    \caption{4}
    \label{fig:4}
\end{figure}
```

not working (text interleaves images).

**option #2:**

```
\begin{figure}[ht!]
        
        \subfloat[functions]{%
            \label{fig:functions}
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{1.png}
        }           
    
        \subfloat[common]{%
            \label{fig:common}
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{2.png}
        }   
        
        \subfloat[helpers]{%
            \label{fig:helpers}
            \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{3.png}
        }       

\end{figure}
```

Last figure disappears. Also, weird unexpected padding to the left.

I need to use **option #1** with **no** text in between.

What I essentially need to do is have a document like:

```
Page 1

    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit 
voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, 
eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto 
beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem 
quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut

Page 2 

Image 1

Image 2

Page 3

Image 3

Page 4

Image 4

Image 5

Page 5

ctetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius 
modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam 
aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam,
 quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit 
laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? 
Quis autem
```

In short, a block of images that succeed one another across pages and don't allow any text in between.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Maybe add a drawing of your intended output.

Comment: Image with page width? Please extend your code fragment to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. In preamble left only to your problem relevant packages. BTW, images heights should be small enough  that can be placed on one page. What you like to achieve with image options: `width=10cm,scale=0.5` ? Such settings are not consistent.

Comment: @Dr. Manuel Kuehner updated

Comment: Please, provide MWE!

Comment: you should put all the images and captions in the _same_ `figure` if you want them to keep together.

Comment: Is the question still relevant? At least, give feedback to the provided answers.

Comment: Yep. One sec. I'll delete this comment after that.

Comment: This is a long second :)

Comment: I voted to close (unclear question and the OP does not respond enough).

Comment: OP's busy as hell but will get back

Answer (score 2):

I assume this fits your needs. The `[H]` option of the `float` package makes sure that there is no text in between.

**Next time,** please provide an MWE (as indicated by Zarko) similar to the code that I provide here (using `\includegraphics{example-image-a}` for example).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

Text

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{example-image-a}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

Text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

On your questions as is now, not provide sufficient information. At least we need to know really size (height) of your images. As I already mentioned in my comment, that images can be fit on one page, they can have enough small heights.

T keep all images together, they need to be in one float `figure`, Something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htp]
    \centering
\includegraphics[height=4cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{1}
    \label{fig:1}

\includegraphics[height=3.5cm, width=10cm]{example-image}
    \caption{2}
    \label{fig:2}

\includegraphics[height=4.5cm, width=10cm]{example-image}
    \caption{3}
    \label{fig:3}

\includegraphics[height=3cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image}
    \caption{4}
    \label{fig:4}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I assume the OP needs page breaks between the pictures. But as you already mentioned, the unclear question makes it difficult :).